# SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE does not work with permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, screen-brightness

In my app I want to change the `SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE` (and set another value). I added the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml (double checked with other parameters in the file). The value of the mode should be changed, when a button was pressed.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(on) {
        ContentResolver cResolver = getContentResolver();
        Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
        Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 50);
    }
}
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The Android device is a Logic Instrument Fieldbook F1 Android-Version 5.0.1

When I try to execute this command I got the following Exception:

```
08-31 15:29:28.471 16613-16613/com.matodayu.oxo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.matodayu.oxo, PID: 16613 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:643)
        at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1094)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1371)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1476)
        at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1470)
        at com.matodayu.oxo.FullscreenActivity$4$1.run(FullscreenActivity.java:184)
        at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5285)
        at com.matodayu.oxo.FullscreenActivity$4.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:179)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4809)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20123)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: No this is not the solution

Comment: What does Settings.System.canWrite() says?

Comment: It does not work. To call Settings.System.canWrite I have to add `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)` to my function. And this will not work on API Level 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you defined your permissions?
Inside the manifest or application tag?

I made a Test-Project and it works. 
It just failed when i added the permission inside the wrong position - e.g. the application tag.

Comment: It does not work both on application and on activity tag... Did your test app also run on API Level 21?

Comment: Sorry this was a false test. I added the permission down the manifest tag and it works. Thank you!!!!