# How to make app like night mode

Tags: android, eclipse

How can make app which will dim screen light.

I want to make simple application which is do screen brightness very low

Dim screen brightness by programatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708692/changing-the-screen-brightness-system-setting-android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251596/screen-brightness-mode-does-not-work-with-permission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Screen Brightness System Setting Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708692/changing-the-screen-brightness-system-setting-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Settings.System
            .putInt(this.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, newBrightnessValue);
```

Use This method. Pass int value at  "newBrightnessValue". you can also pass 0 or 1 for low & high brightness respectivily

Answer (score 0):

The screen design is presented based on Application Theme. By default, we specify the application theme in manifest file. It uses the theme in our application

```
<application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

You can change Dark theme during run time

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dark);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtrKN.png)

Also you can define your own theme in `styles.xml` file